# LG G6 (H870) LineageOS 14.1 - Encryption not working

Tags: encryption, lg, lineageos, 7.1-nougat, lg-g6

I have been waiting for official port of LineageOS to my LG G6 (H870). And yesterday I decided to install the newest version of LineageOS (14.1 20170912) on my G6. I downloaded unlock.bin from LG's official site, unlocked the bootloader, verified the unlock. Then I installed TWRP (3.1.1-0-H870), booted in recovery mode, wiped cache, data, and system partition before I installed LineageOS from zip file (due to the instruction on LineageOS official wiki). I also installed OpenGapps (micro arm64 20170912), and restarted.

Everything worked well until i tried to encrypt the phone. I plug the phone in AC, push «Encrypt phone» button, input my PIN code and verify that I want to encrypt the phone. The phone restart, the phone display the «gear splited» Android mascot (the below one, without the header and progressbar).

[image]

But nothing happens, the phone display it for a few seconds before it continue boot process.

I also discovered that «`Device Storage`» (`Settings` > `Storage Settings`) tells med that «`-14.01 GB used of 7.40 GB`».

Is there someone who has had similary problems? Or know how to fix this?

Comment: At this early stage the devs might not have implemented it - report back on [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g6/development/7-1-2r24-rom-lineageos-t3657486) if necessary.

Comment: AFAIK that is rom related problem, I saw someone reporting same thing but I can't remember where. You should probably report this to rom developer.

Comment: [This LineageOS changelog](https://www.lineageoslog.com/14.1/h870) doesn't show the version you mention, but I do see some unofficial builds with that date. Unofficial builds are often missing features.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not implemented, the patch needs reviewing or something. I spent several days trying to figure it out. If you're into it, you can merge it yourself and rebuild and it should work: https://review.lineageos.org/#/c/165296/ (although I think this patch is for file-based encryption, there is a separate one for full disk encryption).